# How to fix "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in UPDATE statement.'"?

Tags: c#, oledb

I have been getting a syntax error in my UPDATE datagridview code which happens to work in another .cs file. My group has been looking at different solutions online but everything won't work.

My group has been looking at different solutions online but everything won't seem to work.

```
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Update Table1 set treatment = '" + treat.Text + "', remarks = '" + appRemarks.Text + "', cost = '" + treatCost.Text + "', Time = '" + textBox2.Text + "' where lastName = '" + Lastname.Text + "' ";


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully!");
        }
```

The expected output should be Updated Successfully! and it should reflect in the database file after clicking the update button. Sometimes the output is "Microsoft Engine database" which does not save the changes.

The error says "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in UPDATE statement.'" pointing to cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: As the error says something in the query is wrong. Could you please update your question and include the full error message and stacktrace?

Comment: dont use string concat

Comment: please ensure that all table attribute names are spelled correctly.

Comment: Time is in uppercase.

Comment: Constructing query strings like this is the basis of SQL injection attacks. Don't do it, it's not safe. Look at how to create parameterised queries instead (the precise syntax varies based on db provider, but typically your update statement contains place holders like "@1" and then you define the values in these places via a collection of typed parameter objects)

Comment: `Time` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) so would need to be escaped with [ ]. But more importantly, what Steve Todd has stated.

Answer (score 2):

First, never use string concatenation to build a query. You're asking for a SQL Injection attack. The biggest thing I could see here is make sure that only columns that are string columns (varchar, char, text, etc..) have single-quoted values. Is cost a number? If so then it should be:

```
, cost=" + treatCost.Text + ",
```

If cost is a number, also make sure that there isn't a currency amount in the input field. If someone puts in 1,422.00 it's not a number and will fail since , is for decoration.
If someone puts in $1422.00 it's not a number as $ is for decoration.
Either of these would fail the query.

Comment: After changing the cost='" into cost=" , another error is generated System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '', Time = '01:00 PM' where lastName = 'adwwadadsdasd''.'

Comment: Did you remove the single quotes from both sides?

Comment: @Dzeija - Stop using string concatenation.  If you instead use Sql parameters, all of your problems will likely vanish.

Comment: Did you change Time to be [Time] ? Time is a function in access and a reserved word in sql so it should be surrounded by brackets to ensure the query understands that this is a column.

Answer (score 2):

This would happen if someone types an apostrophe into the remarks field, which SQL server will interpret as the ending quote of the string.  But much worse things can happen if the user knows a bit of sql and wants to cause trouble.  For example, putting `'--` in the remarks will result in

```
Update Table1 set treatment = 'blah', remarks = ''-- where lastName = 'foobar'
```

which will overwrite every row in the table, not only the one containing `foobar`.

Use query parameters so that user-provided values can't be interpreted as query keywords and structure.

Instead of `remarks = '" + appRemarks.Text + "'` you will have `remarks = @Remarks` as well as

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Remarks", SqlDbType.NText).Value = appRemarks.Text;
```

and all the other user inputs likewise.